# Locust with different wait time for different tasks

Tags: load, locust

I am working on writing a load test for a websocket endpoint using locust 1.3.2
I have 3 task:

```
task A
      --> send data every 10seconds
task B
   subtask b1
       --> send data every 5 seconds
   subtask b2
       --> send data every 3 seconds
task C
    --> send data every 5 sec
```

There are 3 websocket endpoints on the same host to which data has to be sent using these task.
I am confused as to how to structure my locust file

Should I create separate classes for task A , B and C?

or
should I have 3 tasks in the same class?

or
should I have 3 separate locustfiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to have 3 separate User classes (or maybe even 4, if you mean for the b1/b2 subtasks to run concurrently).

I see no benefit to making separate files.